# Why is positive definiteness required for a global minimum to exist?

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, positive-definite, quadratic-programming

When we optimize

$$\min x'Ax$$

why does matrix $A$ need to be positive definite in order to have a global minimum?

Comment: It is not required. If $A=0$ then there is a global minimum. You need positive semi definite. Otherwise there is a direction in which you can produce values that are unbounded below.

Comment: @copper.hat what is the requirement to have a unique solution?

Comment: Can you guess? Where is the derivative (of a convex function) zero?

Comment: @copper.hat you would want $Ax=0$ has a solution, so the det != 0. and second derivative to be negative. I don't know how could A be expressed to meet this.

Comment: What is the second derivative of $x \mapsto x'Ax$??

Comment: $2A$, but what does it mean for $2A$ to be negative, when $A$ is a matrix?

Comment: The second derivative must be positive semidefinite, which is how this started???

Comment: @copper.hat Say A is $\begin{matrix} 
2 & 6 \\
6 & 18
\end{matrix}$, the objective function $x'Ax >= 0$, but x could be $[3, -1]$ or x could be $[6, -2]$. What kind of A will make the solution unique?

Comment: To have a **unique** minimiser, $A$ should be strictly positive-definite. (In fact, this is "if and only if".)